# Find constant such that inequality is true

Tags: inequality

I have to find $c>0$, such that following inequality is true:
$$-3x^2+2|x||y|-y^2\leq -c(x^2+y^2)$$
for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.
Is there any way to find $c$ except trying random values? What if I want to find the best constant?

Comment: Please specify that you mean for all $x,y$.

Comment: I am not sure why, but by try and error the Euler-Mascheroni-Constant $\gamma \approx 0.5772$ seems to be a good candidate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposed inequality is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
3x^{2} - 2|x||y| + y^{2} \geq c(x^{2} +y^{2}) \Longleftrightarrow (3-c)|x|^{2} - 2|x||y| + (1-c)|y|^{2} \geq0 
\end{align*}

Which is equivalent to $3 - c > 0$ and $\Delta \leq 0$. More precisely, one has
\begin{align*}
4y^{2} - 4(3-c)(1-c)y^{2} \leq 0 & \Longleftrightarrow 4y^{2} - 4(3 - 4c + c^{2})y^{2} \leq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (4 - 12 + 16c - 4c^{2})y^{2} \leq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 4c^{2} - 16c + 8 \geq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow c^{2} - 4c + 2 \geq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (c-2)^{2} - 2 \geq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow c\in(-\infty,2-\sqrt{2}]\cup[2+\sqrt{2},+\infty)
\end{align*}

Since $0 < c < 3$, we conclude that $c\in(0,2-\sqrt{2}]$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Damn, I find it pretty. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad to help.